# Error when installing package via Cabal - kind mis-match

Tags: haskell, cabal-install, arrows

I'm trying to install package from this git repo: https://github.com/dwincort/SettableArrow

I'm in my catalog and typing:

```
cabal install SettableArrow.cabal
```

getting this error on line 187:

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `ArrowSwitch' should have kind `* -> * -> *',
but `a' has kind `*'
In the instance declaration for `ArrowSwitch (SA a)'
```

The line where instance is defined:

```
class Arrow a => ArrowSwitch a where
switch :: (Typeable b, Typeable c) => a b c -> a (b, Maybe (a b c)) c
```

187:

```
instance (Typeable a, ArrowSwitch a, ArrowLoop a , ArrowDelay a) => ArrowSwitch (SA a) where
   switch (SA def) = SA $ loop $ 
     second (delay def) >>> arr (\(((b,msf),et),prevSF) -> 
           ...
```

Is the error on my sidee or is something wrong with the code?
There is a paper on this if someone is interested:

> http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/dwc-yale-formatted-dissertation.pdf

Comment: What version of GHC are you using? Polykinded Typeable (for `Typeable a, ArrowSwitch a, ...`) was new in 7.8 I think.

Comment: @ReidBarton I got 7.6.3. Installing 7.8 right now.